# Laravel $this->auth->logout(); takes too long to process

Tags: php, laravel

this is the logout code

```
info("logout start");
$this->auth->logout();
info("logout one");
session_unset();
```

it took 1 minute for it to process `$this->auth->logout();`

[2022-08-10 08:26:48] production.INFO: logout start
[2022-08-10 08:27:16] production.INFO: logout one

Any idea why this is taking too long?

Laravel Version: 9.23.0

PHP Version: 8.0.21

Also, no listeners for logout and this doesn't happen all the time so very weird.

Comment: Are you using any listener??

Comment: no listeners for logout